# How to remove repeated code between services

Tags: java, design-patterns, service, soa

I have 10 atomic services, each one with its own entities. (Separated projects for each service)

Inside each service I have a Helper that does exacly the same thing but it depends on their entities.

I would like to stop repeating code on every service, so I am creating an utility service that will provide that helper to others and here comes my question:

How can I do that if I have this dependency between the helper and the entities of each service?

This is one example from the helper:

```
...
SomethingPK somethingPK = toSomethingPK(something);
SomethingEntity somethingEntity = (SomethingEntity)session.get(SomethingEntity.class, somethingPK);
somethingEntity = toSomethingEntity(something);
AnotherEntity another = new AnotherEntity();
//attribute sets
somethingEntity.setAnother(another);
...
```

Each service has its own SomethingPK, SomethingEntity and AnotherEntity as mapped entities on Hibernate.
How can I loose this connection?

Makes sense?

*Today: Duplicated code like*

**ServiceABC Project**

```
abc.entities.AbcType (DTO)
abc.entities.AbcEntity (Entity)
abc.entities.AbcPK (Entity's PK)
abc.entities.AbcAnotherEntity (Entity)
abc.helpers.CommonHelper (Bean)



abc.helpers.CommonHelpers.createSomethingThatIsNotBusinessLogic(Session session, AbcType abc) {
        ...
        AbcPK key = parseToAbcPK(abc);
        AbcEntity abcEntity = (AbcEntity)session.get(AbcEntity.class, key);
        abcEntity = parseToAbcEntity(abc);
        AbcAnotherEntity abcAnother = new AbcAnotherEntity();
        AbcEntity.setAnother(another);
        ...
    }
```

**ServiceXYZ Project**

```
xyz.entities.XyzType
xyz.entities.XyzEntity
xyz.entities.XyzPK
xyz.entities.XyzAnotherEntity
xyz.helpers.CommonHelper



xyz.helpers.CommonHelpers.createSomethingThatIsNotBusinessLogic(Session session, XyzType xyz) {
        ...
        XyzPK key = parseToXyzPK(xyz);
        XyzEntity xyzEntity = (XyzEntity)session.get(XyzEntity.class, key);
        xyzEntity = parseToXyzEntity(xyz);
        XyzAnotherEntity xyzAnother = new XyzAnotherEntity();
        XyzEntity.setAnother(another);
        ...
    }
```

*Need refactor to achieve this somthing like this:*

**ServiceABC Project**

```
abc.entities.AbcType (DTO)
abc.entities.AbcEntity (Entity)
abc.entities.AbcPK (Entity's PK)
abc.entities.AbcAnotherEntity (Entity)
```

**ServiceXYZ Project**

```
xyz.entities.XyzType
xyz.entities.XyzEntity
xyz.entities.XyzPK
xyz.entities.XyzAnotherEntity
```

**ServiceUtilities Project**

```
utilities.CommonHelper


utilities.helpers.CommonHelpers.createSomethingThatIsNotBusinessLogic(Session session, ?Type type) {
        ...
        //same code prepared to deal with any entity, entityPK or type.
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't the Generics be of some help here ? you may want to post some code snippet to help answers.

Comment: Some code would be helpful to see but generally I think you will need to decouple your helper from the entities to make it reusable. Either through generics or a common interface, etc.

Comment: While I cannot be sure without some code to show exactly what you're talking about, this sounds like a job for Dependency Injection!!

Comment: I've edited with some code example, hope it helps. :)

Comment: Before posting I have created interfaces and abstract classes on the utility service to represent these entities letting the responsible service extend and map to hibernate but I got stucked when it comes to instantiate AnotherEntity (which I made abstract)... :/

Comment: Also, I cannot see how generics can help me because sometimes I have to instantiate using constructor with fields.

Comment: If those fields are different for all services, you have a problem. Service constructor, must use fields that are going to be used to created the service not it's content. For example: Credentials.

Comment: would help if you give us a little more of your software architecture at service layer.

Comment: Yes, fields are different for each service because they are attributes of different entities. 
The constructors are used on the entities (I haven't explained it very well).

The Service part of the code is ok, the real big deal is this connection with Entities.

I will try to provide more information without compromising corporate information.

Comment: I would like create a new interface called `TpyeParser`, and pass it to your `CommonHelper`, then the duplication for `XyzPK key = parseToXyzPK(xyz);` will disappear, the parse and set logic can be same for all service logic by passing the different `TypeParser`

Comment: I am creating an interceptor to run the common code on the Utilities Service and I will keep the unique code (access to its entities and stuff) inside each service. I will post something when I finish but if you guys have some more ideas in between... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

A moved the common entities to the Utility Service Project but I left the table name empty.
And in every service i created a mapping for an external entity pointing to those entities on the utility service and configure their table names.
Then I was able to move all my helpers to the Utility Service because all related entities were there.
So, in the end, no duplicated code across services and I am still able to have a different table for each one of them.

Thank you for all your help anyways! It was great to make some different approach trying to solve.

How can I mark this question as solved?